# Django unable to find scripts in static folder

Tags: javascript, html, django

This might seem like a duplicate question but I dont whats going on but I have gone through stackoverflow and tried all the solutions but cant find the answer that I need. Here Django finds the style.css but cannot find the App.js and script.js literally located in the same folder as style.css. I cant seem to figure out the problem, I have wasted around 2 hrs trying to figure it out.
UPDATE: I tried hard coding the path and still says it didn't find it while shows up when I do py manage.py findstatic. 
**Relevant HTML**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Reyanna</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://img.icons8.com/nolan/96/bot.png" type="image/icon type">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
  <link rel="script" href="{% static 'App.js' %}">
  <link rel="script" href="{% static 'script.js' %}">
</head>
```

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "home/static",
]
```

**Folders**

- Home(Django App)
- |-> static

  - |-> App.js
  - |-> script.js
  - |-> style.css
- |-> templates

  - |-> index.html

Comment: You need to use the <script> tag for external JS files, try something like: <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'App.js' %}"></script>

Comment: Yes i have tried this too, Doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried a `hard reload` of the browser **CMD + SHIFT + R** ? to force reload static files

Comment: Still gets me the 404 Error

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: I realized templates folder is in App directory**

If your `templates` folder is in your app directory, then:

- Delete this `STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "home/static",]`
- Leave `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` like it is
- Leave `TEMPLATES` >> `DIRS` path empty.
- Last, in your base.html or index.html, add `<scripts>----</scripts>` tags before the closing `body tag` like the following

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

- Clear your browser history including all cookies and reload server.

If it is not successful, I suggest to check for missing closing tag in your html or tag name typo.

But if `templates` folder is within project directory then do the following:

- In `settings.py` >> `TEMPLATES`, paste `DIRS` path like the following

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

- Also copy paste the following in the bottom of settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

- Last, in your base.html or index.html, add `<scripts>----</scripts>` tags before the closing `body tag` like the following

```
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

- Clear your browser history including all cookies and reload server.

If it is not successful, I suggest to check for missing closing tag in your html or tag name typo.

**For exact examples of both, visit my GitHub repo and have a look to `settings.py` and `base.html`**

[Templates folder inside App directory](https://github.com/IT-Support-L2/Django-Todo-API)

[Templates folder within project directory](https://github.com/IT-Support-L2/mytek)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the script tag instead? Then, in the desired template, you'd do:

```
{% load static %}
...
...
...
<script src="{% static '/js/product_to_warehouse.js' %}"></script>
```